# Kaa cluster architecture

Tags: kaa

I am not really understand with Kaa cluster architecture. First is i need to  install and configure Kaa components on a single Linux node by using this link: http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Administration-guide/System-installation/Single-node-installation/

I need to install SQL, NOSQL and Zookeeper in it. Does it means this single node is actually a cluster? i want to implement scalability and high availability. Do i need to clone the single node to implement fail over process?

The Kaa cluster architecture is:
http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Architecture-overview/

Comment: Yes you are right this single node is work as a cluster.

Answer (score 0):

To setup and configure Kaa cluster you should follow the instructions on the [Kaa Cluster setup](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Administration-guide/System-installation/Cluster-setup/) documentation page. The Single Node Installation page describes what Kaa dependencies should be installed and how they should be configured, but as it for a single node installation, they all are placed at single node and configured respectively.

The cluster setup is most like single-node installation, but requires more nodes and configuration for their correct cooperation.

Thus, the difference between Kaa cluster and single-node operation is generally in configuration of the components rather than in the components themself.

Therefore, you can clone a single-node Kaa server as a basis for a cluster node, but you will need to change its configuration accordingly before it can operate as a cluter node correctly.